# Objective C - NSManagedObjectContext and NSFetchedResultsController release handling

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

i need some information about memory management with NSManagedObjectContext objects. 
I`m programming on an ipad-App and i work with core data objects.

My UIApplicationDelegate controls the NSManagedObjectContext:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
if (__managedObjectContext != nil)
{
    return __managedObjectContext;
}

NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
if (coordinator != nil)
{
    __managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [__managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
}
return __managedObjectContext;
}
```

I`m using instances of the ManagedObjectContext to display my Core Data Objects. 
like this.
example table view controller:

```
CRMAppDelegate *appDelegate = (CRMAppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
self.managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;

// Initialize NSFetchedResultsController to retrieve data from the database.
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Contact" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];

// Sort results ascending by last name, first name.
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorFirstLetterLastName = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"firstLetterOfLastName" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorLastName = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name_last" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorFirstName = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name_first" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptorFirstLetterLastName, sortDescriptorLastName, sortDescriptorFirstName, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
[sortDescriptors release];
[sortDescriptorFirstLetterLastName release];
[sortDescriptorFirstName release];
[sortDescriptorLastName release];

/*
if ([self.managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:NULL] == 0) {
    [self reloadContactData];
}
 */

// Create NSFetched Results controller instance.
fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
                            initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                            managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                            sectionNameKeyPath:@"firstLetterOfLastName"
                            cacheName:@"ContactsViewCache"];
[fetchRequest release];
self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

// Load data.
NSError *error;
if (![fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
    // Update to handle the error appropriately.
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
}
```

Is it ok to instance the NSManagedObjectContext like this? Because, the retainCount of the context is increasing til 10 while i`m testing my APP, even though i'm releasing the the context in "viewDidUnload" and "dealloc".

I`ve tried retain the context in a handler class like this:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)getManagedObjectContext
{
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.managedObjectContext autorelease];

return context;
}
```

Whats the best way to interact with NSManagedObjectContext - objects and instances? 
Thx and sry for my stuoid question :)

Comment: Is the `self.managedObjectContext` property in your second code block a strong / retain property, or a weak / assign?

Comment: "object" and "instance" mean the same thing.

Comment: @cocoahero its a retain property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value returned by `retainCount` is meaningless.  Don't bother looking at it.

Use the Leaks instrument or [heapshot analysis](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/) to determine if your app is leaking.

Comment: Thx, i will have a look on it.